# Add manytomany field query in cet_or_create method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        employer = User.objects.get(id=self.context.get('employer'))
        candidate = User.objects.get(id=self.context.get('candidate_id'))
        report_details_id = ReportDetails.objects.filter(
            id__in=self.context.get('report_details_id'))
        (report_candidate, created) = ReportCandidate.objects.get_or_create(
            reported_by=employer.id, candidate_id=candidate.id,report_details_id=report_details_id)
        return report_candidate
```

Here the report_details_id is a manytomanyfield query. How will apply each of the data in it in the get_or_create method?

```
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

I'm getting this error from the above code.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`report_details_id` contain a list of objects thats why you are getting the above error. to fix the issue you just need to use `in` operator.

Like :-

```
   reported_by=employer.id, candidate_id=candidate.id,report_details_id__in=report_details_id)
```